# Sell something for half as much

Tags: nouns

Should I use ''price'' in the sentences below for it to be more formal?

> They will sell the bottles for twice as much price as the negotiated price.

> They will sell the bottles for twice as much as the negotiated price.

Answer (score 2):

Price is not the correct term to use here.  A price is an exact amount, you cannot have more price or less price.  However, you can use "money" or "cost" in this way.

> They will sell the bottles for twice as much money as the negotiated price.

> They will sell the bottle for twice as much cost to them than the negotiated price.

*(Note that I had to use "cost to them", otherwise the meaning could ambiguously be misunderstood as "cost to us", and with this change I had to use "than" instead of "as".)*

Now, while you can't have "more" or "less" price, a price can be "higher" or "lower".  So, we could also use this form:

> They will sell the bottle for twice as high a price than as negotiated.

Comment: Or you could even just leave out any noun at all: *They will sell the bottle for twice the negotiated price.*